# Автоматическое заполнение формы в booking.com

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, скрипт

У меня есть идея автоматического заполнения формы с указанием валюты на `booking.com`, т.к. курс постоянно скачет, а проставлять вручную каждый день это глупо, решил это автоматизировать.

Логика следующая: (язык PHP)
Парсинг данных цен НБРБ => ввод курса в базу mysql => подключение к панели управления `booking.com` через `cURL` (логин форма логин/пароль) => редирект на страницу заполнения курса валют в $ => получение данных формы => получить курс валют из базы mysql => заполнение формы на `booking.com` => нажатие кнопки `input` => статус OK.

А теперь вопрос, я правильно мыслю, и возможно ли это реализовать через `cURL`?

Comment: вы про экстранет или обычный пользовательский интерфейс?

Comment: @ExileeD, Да, извините забыл сказать, я про панель, которая экстранет, там есть заполнение курса валют в одном разделе, и заполнение происходит через обычную форму input, и применяется через button кнопку

Comment: Можно реализовать. Но вам нужно авторизоваться записать куки в файл. И уже с этими куками редактируйте курс. Через курл в букинге тяжеловата авторизоваться (они требуют потверждать новый ПК при заходе) . Если не секрет зачем вам курс  постоянно менять ? сделайте валюту отеля в $ и букинг сам будет конвертировать с другие валюты

Comment: @ExileeD, понял, а если один раз сделать авторизацию с IP адреса (новый пк), после уже не будут требовать подтверждение? Про куки да я понял, курс нужно постоянно менять потому что курс валют скачет каждый день, и получается косяк в валюте, т.е. нужен подгон под цену номера в белорусских рублях (к примеру 750 000 тыс), а на букинг.коме поставили 37,5$, курс подрос и уже получается разбежка, к примеру получается не 750 000 руб, а уже 730 000 руб. за номер, а такого лучше избежать. Но вообще это возможно, я так понимаю?

Comment: Они скорее всего привязывают к устройству. Я не замечал привязки к ip. У нас валюта отеля это евро. И мы снимаем деньги в евро , а уже букинг сам следит за курсом других валют, и сам конвертирует.